# mongodb, pipeline, multiple $group stages

Tags: python, mongodb

I wanna simply get average regional city population for all countries in the cities collection. I think my first group stage works in giving me all the different regions with the avg population of that region. 
My plan was to go to the next stage now, id it by country and then build the avg of all those values i got in my first group stage. Maybe i have an error in my thinking here or more likely my execution, since i am new to mongo db and the pipeline thing. Below my code i put example data.

```
pipeline = [
{ '$unwind' : '$isPartOf'},
{
    "$group":
    {
        "_id":  "$isPartOf",
        "avgpop" : {"$avg":"$population"},        
    }
},
{
    "$group":
    {
        "_id":  "$country",
        "avgpopc" : {"$avg":"$avgpop"},       
    }
}
```

]

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fe1d364b5ab856eea75ebc"),
    "elevation" : 1855,
    "name" : "Kud",
    "country" : "India",
    "lon" : 75.28,
    "lat" : 33.08,
    "isPartOf" : [
        "Jammu and Kashmir",
        "Udhampur district"
    ],
    "timeZone" : [
        "Indian Standard Time"
    ],
    "population" : 1140
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the average regional city population for all countries in the cities collection you need to first calculate the average city population for each region in a country and then calculate the average of all the regional averages for a country.The `_id` field in the first $group pipeline stage should be compound keys, that is, documents composed of multiple fields. In the case above the keys in the **`$group`** `_id` would be the `isPartOf` and `country` fields. This is where you get the average population of each region per country. The next group pipeline stage then calculates the average of all the country's regional population averages. Thus your final aggregation pipeline should look like this:

```
pipeline = [ 
        { "$unwind": "$isPartOf"},
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "Region": "$isPartOf",
                    "Country": "$country"    
                },
                "avgPopulation": {"$avg": "$population"},        
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id.Country" ,
                "avgRegionalPopulation": {"$avg": "$avgPopulation" },        
            }
        }
    ]
```